# working with lists and strings

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a string for example 'winner' and I have a list of the alfabet, how can I check the position of each letter of the string in the list? So for the letter 'w' would give 22. The letter 'i', 8.
I use the `import string` method to initialize the alfabet.

`alfabet = string.ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`ord` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> [ord(i)-ord('a') for i in s]
[22, 8, 13, 13, 4, 17]
```

This won't work if you have mixed upper/lowercases:

```
>>> s2 = 'WinneR'
>>> [ord(i)-ord('a') for i in s2]
[-10, 8, 13, 13, 4, -15]
```

You will have to use the `lower()` function:

```
>>> [ord(i)-ord('a') for i in s2.lower()]
[22, 8, 13, 13, 4, 17]
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker just though about that. Do you think it's more efficient to use lower on the letter or the word?

Comment: yeah I already lowered my string so it works fine with the first one! But one little question. What does that 'a' mean in ord('a')?

Comment: Oh, most certainly `.lower()` on the string is much faster. That's an even better idea.

Comment: It's the letter `'a'`. Since `ord('a')` returns the integer 97, and `ord('b')` 98, etc. you want to substract 97 each time in order to have 0,1...